# Java - validating a subject Code

Tags: java, validation

I have a subject code e.g: ABC123 that is a `string`

I need to ensure that it is of length 6, the first 3 characters are letters and the last 3 are numbers.

I would like to try and do it all in an `if` statement? I can work the length but cannot figure out the numeric and letter part of things. e.g:

```
public void isValidCode(String subjectCode2){
    str = subjectCode2;
    if (str.length() == 6 && """"NEED TO TEST OTHERS HERE??""" ) {
        System.out.println("The code is valid");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The code is not valid");
    }
```

Comment: The regular expression `[a-z]{3})(\d{3})` might work for testing for the first three being letters and the last three being numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use Regular Expressions, and the `matches()` method of the `String` class.

```
if (str.matches("[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}")) {
    // Validation succeeded
}
else {
    // Validation failed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To test that the first three letters are letters, you could use a loop. Similarly, use a loop for testing that the last three digits are numbers. You might find the functions in the [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class helpful.

Comment: The OP "...would like to try and do it all in an if statement..."

Answer (score 1):

I would change the method signature so that it is not a void method but rather declared to return a boolean. Then you could have several if statements that if false returns false. At the bottom, return true if it passes all tests.

```
public boolean isValidCode(String code) {
  if (code.length() != 6) {
     return false;
  }
  // here check if first 3 chars are letters
  // here check if last 3 chars are numbers

  return true;
}
```

Then the calling code can do a println if desired.

```
String test = "ABC123";
if (isValidCode(test)) {
  System.out.println("The code is valid");
} else {
  System.out.println("The code is not valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "letter", you mean to include letters in alphabets other than English, you'll need this.

```
if (str.matches("\\p{L}{3}\\d{3}")) {
```

Here, `\p{L}` matches any character that Unicode considers to be a letter, in any language.